# How can i fix the size for my custom carousel

Tags: html, css, angular, user-interface, carousel

I tried adding an image carousel to my modal,but the carousel shifts dimensions for different image sizes

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can set at fixed height for your carousel using css so that the carousel box is always the same size:

```
. carousel{
  height:400px;
  width:300px;
```

Or you can probably set the height and width for each images you are using in your carousel in the same way

```
. carousel_image{
  height:400px;
  width:300px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try Below code:

```html
<ngb-carousel>
<ng-template ngbSlide>  
<img src="https://d2g9wbak88g7ch.cloudfront.net/bannerimages/46_inr.png" style="height:300px;width:100%">
</ng-template>  
</ngb-carousel>
```

Comment: Also play around the object-fit style if you want to retain the aspect ratio of the image.